# Rendering same component both in try and catch block in React without loosing focus of fields in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, try-catch

I am using an specific component in `ReactJS` which it may happen to throw some errors sometimes so I need to wrap it by `try-catch` block. My problem is that when it throws error I still need the component to be rendered and show the error to the user so I pass error to the component as `prop` if it is thrown. Look at this sample code:

```
myComponent = (error, data) => { /*render component*/}

renderComponent = () => {
     try { 
           /*THE CODE WHICH MAY THROW ERRORS
           BUT MAY ALSO RECEIVE DATA WITHOUT PROBLEM*/

           return this.myComponent(undefined,data); //if everything is fine
         } catch (e) {
           return this.myComponent(e,undefined);
         }
render {
   return ({this.renderComponent()});
}
```

Everything is fine about this structure except one thing which is the fact that each time some errors happen the whole component resets which is logical because we are rendering whole another component (although it looks the same) but it loses the focus of text fields and scrolls up again and so on.

I tried to put `data` and `error` as `state` so they will all be set there inside the `renderComponent` and I'll call `myComponent` separately and pass the state, but in any case I had to use `setState` inside `render` so it causes problem as you know.

So I thought to ask you that what is your idea about this case. Am I unaware about some React capabilities?

Thanks

Comment: Did my reaction answer your question?

Comment: @alsedra I'm so sorry for my no response, but I left the part that I was working for a while and started working on a new branch I'll test your suggestion asap. Sorry again...

Comment: I've editted my answer. I saw a line where I used TypeScript syntax. Should be pure JS now.

Comment: Hmm I see, thanks :) I'll check it in my code.

Comment: Hi @Erfan, any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since React 16 there's a new component-lifecycle called `componentDidCatch`, which is basically a try-catch for components.

With this lifecycle you can catch errors for specific components, so only that subtree of components break instead of the whole application - and you can render different content based on the state.

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html).

In your case you can do something like:

```
class TryCatchComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { hasError: false, error: undefined, errorInfo: undefined };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true, error, errorInfo });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasError, ...errorProps } = this.state;

    if (hasError) {
      const { fallback: FallbackComponent } = this.props;

      return <FallbackComponent {...errorProps} />;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

const SomeErrorDisplayComponent = ({ error, errorInfo }) => (
  <div>{error} or {errorInfo}</div>
);

const SomeComponent = () => (
  <TryCatchComponent fallback={SomeErrorDisplayComponent}>
    <ComponentThatMightCrashSometime />
  </TryCatchComponent>
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, sorry for my late late response, because my project had some problems in this part so I couldn't test your workaround sooner. Good to get to know more about `componentDidCatch` and I assume it should be called every time any error is thrown inside the component. So I removed `try-catch` block and let the lifecycle do its job, but it doesn't and my app breaks. Just to mention the component that throws error is [Query Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html) which sometimes throws error instead of passing it as render prop.